# Display a fixed header after scolling a specific distance in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap affix property to display a header after scrolling to 100px. It works fine when I set `opacity` property to `0.0001` etc. but when I set it to 0 or `display` to `none`. It stops working. Here is a working demo with opacity property - http://jsfiddle.net/gu33f5cm/.

One issue with setting opacity is that it still takes up space in the document and the document appears to be blank at the location of header. This is my CSS code:

**CSS:**

```CSS
#nav.affix {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
transition: 0.6s all;
}
#nav.affix-top {
opacity:0.1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" id="nav">
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="span12"> <a class="brand" href="#">Home</a>

                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of bootstrap are you using? In v3.3.5 there is a separate nav class which works as you require.
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: I am not affixing nav class here. If is a generic header. Also, the point is to not fix it after user has scrolled a distance but make it both visible and fixed after the scroll.

Comment: Yes, exactly but I am not trying to show a navbar. I am trying to show a generic div instead.